# Scrollable Table View in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, scroll, tableview

I have a `tableview` with 6 cells that are visible on the `view`. In total there are 10 cells. When I try to scroll down, the simulator automatically terminates with an exception. Can somebody please help?

I have browsed the internet many times regarding this problem, but haven't been successful.

I get the following exception:

> exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Here is my code for the delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; 
    if( cell == nil ) { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    } 
    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: What value are you returning in your delegate method `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`  ??

Comment: Show us your Datasource methods for tableview

Comment: Here is my code for the delegate method:                          - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = 
 [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
 if( cell == nil ) { 

  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
     reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  
  cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  
  
  
}

 return cell;
}

Comment: Write cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; line outside of if condition.

Comment: i have already tried that dude :(

Comment: how many records in tabledata array & how many no of rows you set on numberofrows method?

Comment: i have set [tableData count] number of rows

Comment: but why are you hiding 4 rows any reason ? if you tell then i can help in better way.

Comment: guys i have fixed the problem. I was defining the array in the view did Load method of the same class. Now I am declaring it in AppDelegate and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

check your array. It has 9 values. And your table trying to get 10th index in your array.